# How to send two videos by gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

Dears

I'm looking for a way to put two videos side by side and send them in H.264.

```html
#!/bin/bash
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
filesrc location="/home/namako/tairyou_2.mp4" \
! decodebin \
! videoscale \
! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,width=240" \
! videoconvert \
! videomixer.sink_0 \
\
filesrc location="/home/namako/tairyou_2.mp4" \
! decodebin \
! videoscale \
! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,width=240" \
! videoconvert \
! videomixer.sink_1 \
\
videomixer background=1 name=videomixer sink_0::xpos=0 sink_0::ypos=0 sink_1::xpos=512 sink_1::ypos=0 \
! decodebin \
! videoscale \
! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,width=240" \
! videoconvert \
! x264enc \
! rtph264pay \
! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

I did the above code, but the following "error" was displayed.

```html
パイプラインを一時停止 (PAUSED) にしています...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Redistribute latency...
Redistribute latency...
Redistribute latency...
Redistribute latency...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstX264Enc:x264enc0: Can not initialize x264 encoder.
追加のデバッグ情報:
gstx264enc.c(1587): gst_x264_enc_init_encoder (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstX264Enc:x264enc0
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

It seems that h.264 can not be encoded.

Also, using the above code, it becomes the following pipeline connection diagram.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1AKP.jpg)

In the connection diagram, the videomixer input is mpeg2 but the output is jpeg.

What should I do to output in mpeg2, H.264?

Comment: Hi, gstreamer has a verbosity option that can help us. Can you run `GST_DEBUG=3 ./your_script.sh` , and share the output here?

Comment: The debug result is here.  https://writening.net/page?2cEQCj

Comment: The `x264enc` gives the error `ERROR x264enc :0::<x264enc0> height not divisible by 2 (240x135)`. Is your video height 135? If so you might want to resize your input or add a line in your videomixer element.

Comment: Thanks!  I was able to encode in H.264 by resizing the video size of Videomixer.
It was also possible to send.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks!
The video can be played with the following code.

```html
#!/bin/bash
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
filesrc location="filename" \
! decodebin \
! videoscale \
! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,width=480,height=270" \
! videoconvert \
! videomixer.sink_0 \
\
filesrc location="filename" \
! decodebin \
! videoscale \
! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,width=480,height=270" \
! videoconvert \
! videomixer.sink_1 \
\
videomixer background=1 name=videomixer sink_0::xpos=0 sink_0::ypos=0 sink_1::xpos=480 sink_1::ypos=0 \
! decodebin \
! videoscale \
! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,width=480,height=270" \
! videoconvert \
! x264enc \
! rtph264pay \
! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```